# Problem facing while deploying Streamlit app

Tags: python, python-3.x, cloud, streamlit

I am developing a Streamlit web app (using Python). While deploying my web app on Streamlit cloud, a strange error is shown on the screen telling me:

> :exclamation: Updating the app files has failed: open /home/appuser/.ssh/id_github: no such file or directory

The log image is here:

[image]

I do not understand why it gives me this type of error when I don’t have these files or folders in my local app folder.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your GitHub SSH keys have expired. If you unlink your Streamlit Cloud account from GitHub, then re-link them, that should resolve the issue.